# ChromeDriver.exe crashing upon clean up / quit on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Pretty much what it says in the title. I have:

```
public void Cleanup()
{
    WebDriver.Quit();
}
```

Nothing in my code's changed. I guess it's possible that Chrome itself got updated?

It works perfectly on my local Windows 7 machine, which has the same version of Chrome (44).

I tried updating to the latest ChromeDriver.exe 2.16, but it didn't help.
We're running four tests in parallel.

I've seen other threads that suggest using .Close() instead, but I feel like one shouldn't have to do that (and that's if it even works).

Right now I'm trying to update to Selenium.Support and Selenium.WebDriver 2.47 NuGet packages...

Has anyone else had this problem?

[image]

Comment: What version of Chrome? What version of Windows?

Comment: That's already in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You mention the option of calling `Close()` instead. That closes the browser window(s) but leaves the chromedriver open. What I do is to call both:

```
public void Cleanup()
{
    WebDriver.Close();
    WebDriver.Quit();
}
```